# How can I delete the rows containing NA values in multiple columns using R?

Tags: r

[Please view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqmiy.png)
Please view the attached image.I want to delete the rows containing NA in airsystemdelay,securitydelay,airlinedelay,lateaircraftdelay,waeatherdelay

Comment: using `sum`, if the result is `NA` just remove

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove rows where any of columns 3 to 7 are NA:

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df[,c(3:7)]),]
```